# How do I use jQuery to redirect to variable URL?

Tags: jquery, variables, url, redirect, button

I'm trying to make a photo gallery for my portfolio. I've hit a wall and can't work out why this won't work:

It's a button that sends you to a URL depending on your current URL.

In this example, the user is at "/project1.html" and by clicking the next button, will be directed to "/project2.html"

```
<button class="next"><img src="images/next.png" class="next-prev-button" alt="Next"></button>
```

^^^ Button in html

```
<script>
    var projectnumber = 1;

    $( ".next" ).click(function() {
        projectnumber = projectnumber + 1;
        window.location = "project" + projectnumber + ".html";
    )};
</script>
```

When I click the button, nothing happens.

Comment: your closing script it's wrong, change it to });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have wrong sequence of brackets (In the end of script ')}' should be '})')

```
$( ".next" ).click(function() {
    projectnumber = projectnumber + 1;
    window.location = "project" + projectnumber + ".html";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the projectnumber variable is getting reset on loading or every page so it will always be 2.

Try to get the current project number from the url

```
$(".next").click(function () {
    var projectnumber = +location.pathname.split('/').pop()[0].match(/\d+/)[0] + 1;
    window.location = "project" + projectnumber + ".html";)
});
```